# Translation editor android

Tags: android, string, kotlin, translation

I am using translation editor, and to use the translation I have created, I use in the xml @string/example_01.

But how can I use it in the activity like this example?

`progressDialog.setTitle("@string/PleaseWait")`

Comment: `@string/example_01` is XML syntax - in code, the equivalent ID is `R.string.example_01`, which you can pass to functions like `setTitle` or `getString`. That's the same whether you're using translations or not - if you have translations available, it'll pull the appropriate string depending on locale. Like Martin says below, you might need to rename ``PleaseWait`` to your typical snake case `please_wait`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `R.string.example_01`, while `PleaseWait` might not work (all lowercase + underscores).

When writing `R.` you'll see all kinds of Android [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).